# R dataframe: how to find item in one column but not another column (two column contain similar lists)

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
temp = data.frame(current=c("apple, banana, pear", "melon"), 
new=c("apple, cherry, grape", "melon, blueberry"))
```

How can I find what's new in the new column, in this case "cherry, grape" and "blueberry"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is

```
mapply(function(x, y) toString(setdiff(x, y)),
      strsplit(as.character(temp$new), ", "), strsplit(as.character(temp$current), ", "))
#[1] "cherry, grape" "blueberry"
```